# Identify special character in a string which has mix of Arabic and alphanumeric and special character

Tags: special-characters, arabic, alphanumeric, regexp-like

I have a requirement where I need to identify if a string has any special/junk characters excluding Arabic and alphanumeric and space. I have tried below, but its not detecting spl character

```
select count(*) from table
where not regexp_like (column1,UNISTR('[\0600-\06FF\0750-\077F\0870-\089F\08A0-\08FF\FB50-\FDFF\FE70-\FEFF\0030-\0039\0041-\005A\0061-\007A]'));
```

column has following value `'طًيAa1@#$'`

Comment: Pleae specify the RDBMS you're using. Is it Oracle? If so, what version. Please also give the table definition, so that we can see that column's data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `NOT REGEXP_LIKE(column, allowed_characters)`

This means that any string with at least one allowed character will return TRUE from the regular expression, and so be excluded by the WHERE clause.

You want `REGEXP_LIKE(column, disallowed_characters)`

This will identify any strings that have at least one disallowed character.

You can accomplish this with `^` inside the regular expression (`^` meaning 'not any of these characters')

```
select count(*) from table
where regexp_like (Column1, UNISTR('[^\0600-\06FF\0750-\077F\0870-\089F\08A0-\08FF\FB50-\FDFF\FE70-\FEFF\0030-\0039\0041-\005A\0061-\007A]'));
```

Demo; https://dbfiddle.uk/Rq1Zzopk